# tf.cond() returning a tensor of shape unknown

Tags: keras, conditional-statements, tensorflow2.0

Below is the function that I am passing to a keras Lambda layer.

I am getting a problem with the output of `tf.cond()`. It returns a shape of `<unknown>`. The input tensor (t) and the constant weight tensor have shapes of `(None,6)` and `(6,)`, respectively. When I add these two outside of `tf.cond()` then I get a tensor of shape `(None,6)`, which is what I need it to be. However, when the same add operation is returned from within `tf.cond()`, I get a tensor of shape `<unknown>`.

What changes when this operation goes via `tf.cond()`.

```
def class_segmentation(t):

        class_segments = tf.constant([0,0,1,1,2,2])

        a = tf.math.segment_mean(t, class_segments, name=None)

        b = tf.math.argmax(a)
  
        left_weights = tf.constant([1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
        middle_weights = tf.constant([0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0])
        right_weights = tf.constant([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0])
        zero_weights = tf.constant([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])

        c = tf.cond(tf.math.equal(b,0), lambda: tf.math.add(t, left_weights), lambda: zero_weights)
        d = tf.cond(tf.math.equal(b,1), lambda: tf.math.add(t, middle_weights ), lambda: zero_weights)
        e = tf.cond(tf.math.equal(b,2), lambda: tf.math.add(t, right_weights), lambda: zero_weights)

        f = tf.math.add_n([c,d,e])
        print("Tensor shape: ", f.shape) # returns "Unknown"
        
        return f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.

1. [`tf.math.segment_mean()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_mean) expects `class_segments` to have the same shape as first dimension of your input `t`. So `None` must be equal `6` in order for your code to run. This is most likely cause of you getting the *unknown* shape -  because the shape of your tensors depends on `None` which is determined on runtime. You could apply transformation for your code to run (not sure if that is what you are trying to achieve), eg.

```py
a = tf.math.segment_mean(tf.transpose(t), class_segments)
```

2. In [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) `true_fn` and `false_fn` must return tensors of same shape. In your case  `true_fn` returns `(None, 6)` because of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `false_fn` returns tensor of shape `(6,)`.
3. The predicate in [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) must be reduced to a rank 0. For example, if you were to apply
   `b = tf.math.argmax(tf.math.segment_mean(tf.transpose(t), class_segments), 0)`
   then the shape of `b` would be `(None)` and the predicate `pred` in [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) will be [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the same shape (which will raise an error).

Comment: Thank you for your response Vlad. The entire function does work. The segmentation of the input tensor, the condition is based on a rank 0 tensor and even the final output is correct. The only issue is the shape when I input a broadcasted tensor shape. As such, I think point 2 is the source of the issue. I will investigate further and revert...